# Fluent API with view model classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I kinda answered my previous question about data annotations. I have discovered the wonderful world of Fluent API.

I am wondering how this works when you have view model classes though - I am using view model classes in my application and copying the results of posts into model classes that are tracked by EF. How do I tie the data validation performed by Fluent API to my view model classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Fluent API. Fluent API is used for mapping relations between objects. Try to search web for Fluent Validation.